# Repeat PHP inside Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to get and repeat my data from mysql, inside a javascript code.

Javascript Code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
    ]
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9']
    }
}});
```

I need change 'cat1' , 'cat2' , 'cat3'... for data from mysql. I use this code to get and repeat the info :

```
<?php do { ?>
       <?php echo $row_cat['category_name']; ?>
<?php } while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)); ?>
```

This works fine for me,but I can't use this inside javascript code. Do you know how can I make this work ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not read your data into an appropriate array and then output into javascript using `echo json_encode($array)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally just build your data structure in PHP and then output in javascript as a variable via `json_encode`.  So something like:

```
$cat_names = array();
while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)) {
    $cat_names[] = $row_cat['category_name'];
}
```

Then in javascript:

```
var categories = <?php echo json_encode($cat_names); )?>;
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: categories
        }
    }
});
```

This is much, much cleaner and easier to read than trying to echo out HTML/javascript source with each iteration of the database read loop.

Note the change away from do...while  I don't know why you would use that structure here for reading data out of a database. You also shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions at all, but that is another story...

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this but that adds jQuery... The javascript code would be in a javascript file not inline like this. And of course Doctrine/PDO instead of mysql_ commands...

```
<?php
$cats = [];
while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)) {
       $cats[] = $row_cat['category_name'];
}

$charData = [
    "data" => [
        "columns" => [
            ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
        ]
    ],
    "axis" => [
        "x" => [
            "type" => "category",
            "categories" => $cats,
        ]
    ]
];
?>
<script type="application/json" class="chardata"><?=json_encode($charData)?></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
jQuery(function($) {
    $("script.chardata").each(function(i) {
        window.chart = window.chart || [];
        window.chart[i] = c3.generate($.parseJSON($(this).html()));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
<?php $cats=array(); do { ?>
    <?php $cats[] = '"'.$row_cat['category_name'].'"'; ?>
<?php } while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)); ?>

var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
    ]
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: [<?=implode(",", $cats)?>]
}
}});
```

Comment: You should really use json_encode to write json. It's so easy to get it wrong.

Comment: OIS, I had actually added the single quotes in $cats[]="'".$row_cat['category_name']."'". So your edit does not work. I'm perfectly aware that json_encode would be nicer - that's just not what he asks for. He could also build a web service and fetch the data with an ajax request. I just gave a simple way to approach it by combining his own two code snippets above.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that sorry. (btw always use " around strings in json)

Comment: You're right, I'll fix that. And still with you on the json_encode, for sure :)